# SQLPLUS Connection to DB with special characters '@'

Tags: oracle, special-characters, sqlplus

I'm trying to connect to my remote db with a user who has an @ in his password.

I use sqlplus v19 with an OracleClient and my remote db is an OracleServer v19 aswell. I had no problem during the alter user command on the database :

`alter user USER identified by "P@ssword123";` 
`user altered.`

Below are the commands I tried to connect with this user :

`sqlplus USER/"P@ssword123"@tnsname` 
`sqlplus USER/'"P@ssword123"'@tnsname` 
`sqlplus 'USER/"P@ssword123"'@tnsname` 
`sqlplus USER/\"P@ssword123\"@tnsname`

And some variants of those commands.
This always return me the same TNS error : 
`TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

It looks like these solutions works for old sqlplus versions but I can't figure out how can I solve my problem with this version 19.

Of course, I tried to change the password with non @ character and it works but this is not a possible solution in my specific case.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux client to Connect? Might try : `sqlplus USER/\"P@ssword123"@tnsname`

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm using Linux client. With @PCir answer, i get a prompt because de the first double quote is escape

Comment: The workaround is to do sqlplus /nolog, and then use connect user/"P@ssword"@//.... and it works.
SQL> connect tat/"T@AT"@//localhost/pdbbct
Connected.

Comment: Thank you @gsalem, indeed it works well. But how can I use this in a script ?

Comment: Maybe `sqlplus USER/P\@ssword123@tnsname`?

Comment: Didn't notice in my post but I ever tried this @WernfriedDomscheit, doesn't work :/

Comment: if your script is running a commands from a sql file, add this 'connect....' to the sql file

Comment: One other (and more secure) alternative here would be to use an Oracle Wallet to hold the username and password. Then you don't have to include it in the command line or script at all, and most special characters should cease to be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for all your informations @gsalem, it looks like it works well. I'm trying now to do this stuff with a PL/SQL script. But that's another subject !

Comment: For future reference, depending on the OS and the client involved, many special characters are problematic when used in passwords from the command line. In my experience, the only one that works universally is the underscore: `_`.

Comment: Thank you @pmdba, I will check Oracle Wallet, didn't know that solution. And yes I know, mostly for the @ characters, but unfortunatly, I'm not really the one who decide the passwords specifications

Comment: _"I'm not really the one who decide the passwords specifications"_  Perhaps you should be talking to the guy who _does_ decide, and explain the problematic characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your replies. 
I figure it out with your help. I even modified it to make it compatible with a PL/SQL Script which I pass some variables. 
The answer :

> sqlplus /NOLOG << EOF 
> connect USER/"P@ssword123"@tnsname 
> @script_plsql.sql $var1 $var2 $var3 
> EOF